# how to programatically output menu submenu

Tags: routes, blocks

I know that the menu_block module allows you to display a sub menu of a menu with a specified menu depth. How can I do this programatically? I see that using

```
menu_tree_page_data()
```

you can set a maximum depth, but no way of specifying the Starting level, as you would from the Menu Block UI page.